# deploy RESTAPI folder inside Tomcat and use it locally

Tags: angularjs, rest, tomcat

I have a question which I saw lots of articles about that but they could not help me. I have  a folder on my PC which contains my restAPI which is written in java,In addition I have tomcat installed on my PC, I am windows 10 user. How can I deploy this restAPI inside my tomcat (locally) and then use it in my application(my application has been written in angular js). Any kind of help will be appreciated.